# Deselect combobox selected value

Tags: vb.net

First of all, I apologize to the community because the title may seem a bit 'misleading from what actually is the real problem.
I have made a code that populates two combobox with the same values, with each change that occurs on the combobox I perform a check to see if the selected value is equal to another combobox; if it is equal, then execute a particular code otherwise proceed.
I need to implement a de-selection of value and I did it with:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 
Combobox2.SelectedIndex = -1
```

This works fine, but the code that checks if the values are equal interfere with this operation.
In fact, within each combobox I have something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = ComboBox2.SelectedIndex Then
MsgBox ("You can not compare two equal teams", "Warning")
off ()
End If
...
```

where "off ()" is the function that then doesn't continue what you're doing.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Cant you create variables to hold these values, then do the comparisons?

Comment: Be carefull : You are setting ComboBox`1` and ComboBox`2` .SelectedIndex to -1 while you are comparing ComboBox`2` and ComboBox`3` .SelectedIndex. Typo maybe, and of course, doesn't solve the interfering events, but this could lead in misunderstanding of the real issue.

Comment: This is a just example for you..

Comment: You could also update your title and change it to something more precise like _"Cascading ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event interference"_ or _"How to temporarly disable ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event handling ?"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to disable the event when resetting the combobox. This can be done by removing the event with RemoveHandler/AddHandler and adding it again.

An other option is to use a flag. (This is just an example to show an idea, the flag variable should be properly placed).

```
Private FreezeEventFlag As Boolean = False ' or True, it depends..
' Declare it toplevel, initialize its value depending on
' the way you're going to initialize your Comboboxes selected values.
' Then set it's value to True each time you want to
' disable the event handling in any code block that resets
' SelectedIndexes to -1 like below :

    ' ...
    FreezeEventFlag = True
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 
    Combobox2.SelectedIndex = -1
    FreezeEventFlag = False ' Don't forget to set the Flag to false !

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

    If FreezeEventFlag Then Exit Sub ' Just ignore this event this time.

    If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = ComboBox2.SelectedIndex Then
        MsgBox ("You can not compare two equal teams", "Warning")
        off ()
    End If
End Sub
```