# MS Access Deselect Combo Box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I built a billing database for the billing group at work.  The billing team member opens the DB then imports a file, then selects the client that they are billing from a Combo Dropdown and then runs the bill.  The row source of the ComboBox is a query based off of a table called `PendingEOI`.  If the ComboBox is selected when the billing team member attempts to import the file they are unable to do so and are shown an error message stating that the table can't be overwritten at this time.  Is there a way that I can make sure that the ComboBox is never selected?  For instance is there something like an AfterUpdate ComboBox.deselect?  (I know that this specific command doesn't exist).  Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deselect combobox selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934030/deselect-combobox-selected-value)

Comment: Do you mean a value has been selected from the combobox dropdown and this interferes with code? Perhaps because the form and combobox are bound to data and selecting value initiates record edit?

Comment: I think that may be the issue.  When the user select the dropdown it activates the table and thus doesn't allow me to edit the table through VBA?  Not sure to be honest